# Does safari utilize an internal DNS cache?

Tags: safari

As far as I can tell, the Safari browser doesn't have an internal DNS cache. Does anyone know if it does? All other major browsers have some form of DNS cache, and I'm wondering if Safari is the only browser to not have one, instead using OSX's internal cache instead.

Comment: How does one tell if a browser uses an internal cache?

Comment: For example, in Chrome/chromium, the internal cache can be observed via chrome://net-internals/#dns

Comment: As for *telling* if a browser uses an internal DNS cache, I suppose one could perform a series of experiments where DNS records under a short TTL were modified, and checking how long it takes for a browser to observe that change. I don't have a mac system however, and I don't want to go to the effort of running a VM just to perform this tedious kind of testing on safari...

Comment: "All other major browsers have some form of DNS cache" - citation-needed. MSIE in particular depends on the Windows DNS resolver (and thus, on its cache). That said, a browser vendor who is also the vendor of the underlying OS would not have a reason to build *another* DNS cache; whereas e.g. with Firefox, using a cache (or at least an abstraction to make various OSes behave in a similarly predictable way) this makes sense.

Comment: Sure, I'll provide links. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/263558 Microsoft support pages, http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.dnsCacheExpiration Mozilla documents, and Chrome I provided an example in a previous comment. Opera implements a 10 minute cache; but that documentation isn't publicly available. As per the OS caching vs application - retrieving information from this cache requires an RPC call which takes time, so IE implements an internal DNS cache as well. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/09/26/dns-lookups-caching-failover-in-internet-explorer-and-wininet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Safari support DNS prefetch, which uses the [system-wide cache](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=167302#c8) to store DNS records external entities referenced in the HTML source which match the prefetch domain such as:

- links
- images
- CSS
- JavaScript
- audio/video

**References**

- [167302 – [SOUP] DNS prefetch is always done in the default session](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=167302)
- [Can I use Resource Hints: dns-prefetch](https://caniuse.com/link-rel-dns-prefetch)
- [X-DNS-Prefetch-Control - HTTP | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-DNS-Prefetch-Control)